# How to change table object name in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a table named `Product`. Every time I create a object using the table `django` automatically names it as `Product object(1)`, `Product object(2)` and so forth.

Instead of `Project object(1)` I want to name it something creative. In my `Product Table` I have a field called `Product Name`. Whatever I insert into this field I want that to be the name of the object. If I insert `Pen`, it should simply show `Pen` not `Product object(1)` or anything like that.

I am attaching a picture so you guys can understand my problem clearly.[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to override model's `__str__` method:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Can I return a combination of two fields?

Comment: @RubelHosen yes, you can return in `__str__` method any string value. For example: `return self.title + ' ' + self.field2`.

Answer (score 4):

You should define a `__str__` method for your model.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

If you need to support Python 2, then use the `python_2_unicode_compatible` decorator. If you are only supporting Python 2, you can define `__unicode__` instead.

```
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

See the docs for the [`__str__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#str) method for more info.